# Multiple repositories in Maven with the same package

Tags: maven

Assuming I have this in my settings.xml file:

```
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>one</id>
      <name>release</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/A</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>two</id>
      <name>snapshot</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/B</url>
    </repository>
```

Both URLs contain a package called `org.apache.something` but different versions. How do  I force maven to choose from `A` and not`B`.

Comment: Well, in your Maven dependency, you specify a version. So you just need to specify the version of the artifact stored in A.

Answer (score 1):

Since repository A is handling release versions and B is handling snapshots I'm expecting no conflict between them.

Simply declaring your dependency version should guide the choice between them.

Remember however that repository are searched in the order you declare them, so the first one owning the version you declare will win.

But again I expect no differences on same artifact+stable_version among different repositories.